# Observable .map is not a function

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm going nuts! As side-effects for a React/Nextjs application I'm trying 
to use `redux-observable` to get a basic ajax request going:

```
import {combineEpics} from 'redux-observable'
import {mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {ajax} from 'rxjs/ajax'

const fetchSearchEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType('FETCH_SEARCH')
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(action => 
        ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:3001/search/${action.payload.query}`)
            .map(response => ({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_FULFILLED, response }))
      )
)

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  fetchSearchEpic
)
```

But I can't for the life of me get this working. The request is not being fired and the error I keep getting is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_ajax__.a.getJSON(...).map is not a function
```

Now I'm guessing it probably has to do with the new RxJS 6 way of importing dependencies, and somehow I need to import .map to add it to Observable, but how?

I've tried:

```
import 'rxjs'
import 'rxjs/observable/map'
import {map} from 'rxjs/observable'
```

None have the desired effect...

Versions:

```
"react": "16.4.0",
"redux": "4.0.0",
"react-redux": "5.0.7",
"redux-observable": "1.0.0-beta.2",
"rxjs": "6.2.1"
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: I've read that, no help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`map` (along with other Rx operators) no longer exist on the prototype of `Observable` since RxJS 6, for [a few reasons](https://v6.rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators#why-).

Operators are now instead chained using `pipe`:

```
ajax.getJSON(`http://localhost:3001/search/${action.payload.query}`)
    .pipe(map(response => ({ type: FETCH_SEARCH_FULFILLED, response })
```

Make sure to import `map` like so:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

See [Pipeable Operators](https://v6.rxjs.dev/guide/v6/pipeable-operators) which outlines these changes.

Comment: Thanks that works and makes sense now! The internet is filled with inconsistent examples but I knew it could be done without relying on rxjs-compat